need some amount of ether for getting the fake ether to learn blockchain
actually i was trying to get the LineaETH on Linea Sepolia test network. when i visited Alchemy(https://www.alchemy.com/faucets/ethereum-sepolia) for same, it is asking for to have some amount of ETH in mainnet account i.e. proper message was "To receive Goerli ETH, your wallet must have a minimum balance of 0.001 ETH on mainnet. Please add ETH to your wallet and try again." But the problem is i actually do not need real one, i just wants to have fake ether for my learning as i am a beginner and want to learn blockchain. **Is anybody here who can send me some amount, so that i could get the fake ethers and i'll be really thankful to u. my Metamaask wallet is : "0x3A029244265Dc129607E24D8021E427f01fFdce4"

This post might be helpful.

You can use https://cloud.google.com/application/web3/faucet/ethereum/sepolia which gives you 0.05 ETH (Testnet) daily.
